# Is this sentence grammatically correct

Tags: tenses

**As soon as he noticed that he had made a mistake, he informed his boss about it.**

I mean for the past perfect tense, we have here 3 actions (verbs) in the past.  are the verbs' tense grammatically correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah. There are three tensed verbs, but two of them happen at the same past time and the other one is properly past perfect because it happened at a prior past time.

Comment: Why do you think not? See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: I think it's correct.